# Does ArrayList.clear() method frees memory?

Tags: java, android, memory, arraylist

If I'm not mistaken, ArrayList contains the value of memory locations in which the variables you've added to the List are stored. So, my assumption is that when you call ArrayList.clear() method it only frees the aforementioned values (of memory locations) but doesn't free those memory locations themselves. I'll try to illustrate this with an example:

Let's say you've got current status of memory:

```
[Memory location] (type of variable) *value*

[1000] (int) 32

[1002] (int) 12

[1003] (float) 2.5
```

And you add them to the list myList, so it contains pointers to the 1000, 1002, 1003 memory locations.

When you call myList.clear() the pointers will be nullified, but the memory locations 1000, 1002, 1003 would still contain previously given values. Am I wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757868/map-clear-vs-new-map-which-one-will-be-better can help you

Comment: Note that `ArrayList` never contains primitives like `int`, but objects like `Integer`. This ends up being fairly important to the answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are correct because the memory is cleared asynchronously by the Garbage collector, and not directly by such library functions. `clear` would only `null` them all out, and update the `ArrayList` state accordingly.

If any or all of those elements are not not referenced by any other portion of your code, they become eligible for garbage collection, and might be destroyed + de-allocated any time from shortly after that call to the end of time.

Comment: Thanks I'll make sure I manually take care of the discarded variables :) Cheers and nice avatar

Comment: @NitroNbg, There should be no need to manually do anything, as long as they are not referenced, they will be de allocated. And thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

`clear` only nulls backing array elements

```
public void clear() {
    modCount++;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        elementData[i] = null;
    size = 0;
}
```

but if we call `ArrayList.trimToSize` `after clear` backing array will shrink

```
public void trimToSize() {
    modCount++;
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    if (size < oldCapacity) {
        elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
    }
}
```

Comment: This ends up, in the context of the question, wasting space doesnt it? Since it is now not only the cleared elements, but also the Array itself that is in GC limbo

Answer (score 6):

No,It wont clear the memory.After you `clear()`.

See the source code of clear()

```
 public void More ...clear() {
    modCount++;

    // Let gc do its work
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       elementData[i] = null;   
       size = 0;
    }
```

The method is making the elements eligible for Garbage Collector.Not clearing them immediately. Once GC run's,They are gone.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question, it will not `FREE` the memory. It will just remove all the `object references`. Now these objects may or may not be collected by `garbage` collector depending on how they  are referenced at other places.

For instance,

```
Object 1 refers - > Object 2
ArrayList refers - > Object 2
ArrayList refers - > Object 3
```

In this case, after `Arraylist.clear()`, object 3 will be eligible for `clean-up` but not object 2.