# Most efficient way to clear a Java HashMap

Tags: java

Using Java, I have a Map interface which has some items.  I want to clear all the data in it to use it again.  Which method is more efficient?

```
params.clear()
```

or

```
params = new HashMap();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757868/map-clear-vs-new-map-which-one-will-be-better

Comment: `clear()` will reuse more objects (at least 1 depending on the implementation). How the runtimes of `clear()` and running the constructor of `HashMap` compare is implementation dependent.

I would guess `clear()` runs faster.

Comment: Maybe you should write a test and evaluate the performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer `clear()` because you can have the `Map` as `final` member.

```
class Foo {
    private final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    void add(String string) {
        map.put(string, "a value");
    }

    void clear() {
        map.clear();
    }
}
```

If you assign a new `Map` every time you can run into multithreading issues.

---

Below is an almost threadsafe example for using a `Map` wrapped in `Collections.synchronizedMap` but it assigns a new map every time you clear it.

```
class MapPrinter {

    private static Map<String, String> createNewMap() {
        return Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, String>());
    }

    private Map<String, String> map = createNewMap();

    void add(String key, String value) {
        // put is atomic due to synchronizedMap
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    void printKeys() {
        // to iterate, we need to synchronize on the map
        synchronized (map) {
            for (String key : map.values()) {
                System.out.println("Key:" + key);
            }
        }
    }

    void clear() {
        // hmmm.. this does not look right
        synchronized(map) {
            map = createNewMap();
        }
    }
}
```

The `clear` method is responsible for a big problem: `synchonized(map)` will no longer work as intended since the `map` object can change and now two threads can simultanously be within those `synchronized` blocks since they don't lock the same object. To make that actually threadsafe we would either have to synchronize completely externally (and `.synchronizedMap` would be useless) or we could simply make it `final` and use `Map.clear()`.

```
void clear() {
    // atomic via synchronizedMap
    map.clear();
}
```

---

Other advantages of a `final Map` (or anything `final`)

- No extra logic to check for `null` or to create a new one. The overhead in code you may have to write to change the map can be quite a lot.
- No accidential forgetting to assign a `Map`
- "Effective Java #13: Favor Immutability" - while the map is mutable, our reference is not.

Comment: What kind of issues are you talking about? I can't see how this is better than creating a new `Map` in that respect.

Comment: @zapl : You have defined your map as final, so, you have to clear it only. And, What are those multithreading issues?

Comment: any thread is guaranteed to see a `final` variable. Everything non final may need `volatile` or other synchronization methods. Also `synchronized(map)` would fail if you create a new map because threads could synchronize on different objects.

Comment: I suppose this is an better argument than performance (which i suspect is not a big issue here). And i think that `.clear()` makes the programmers intention to discard some previously known values more clear than creating a new map.

Comment: @zapl while that is a good argument, the example you propose is not thread safe either (for example `map.clear()` is not atomic and may actually throw an exception if `add` is called concurrently)... And that does not really answer the question of "which is more efficient".

Comment: @assylias true, the example was not intended to show that. I'll add one.

Comment: @zapl What I'm saying is that HashMap is not thread safe anyway, so whether you clear it or use `new HashMap` doesn't make a difference from a thread safety perspective: you will have to add synchronization in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

In general:
if you don't know how `clear()` is implemented, you can't guess which one would be more performant. I can come up with synthetic use-cases where one or another would definitely win.
If your map does not hold millions and millions or records you can go either way. Performance would be the same.

Specifically:
HashMap clears by wiping content of the inner array. Making old map content available for GC immediately. When you create a new Hashmap it also makes old map content available for GC + the HashMap object itself. You are trading a few CPU cycles for slightly less memory to GC

You need to consider other issue:

- Do you pass this reference to some other code/component? You might want to use `clear()` so that this other code sees your changes, reverse is also true
- Do you want no-hassle, no side-effect new map? I'd go with creating a new one.
- etc