# Original HashMap is modified

Tags: java, hashmap, copy

I have a method which looks for the smallest `substring` from the input string which contains group of `A`, `C`, `G`, `T` letters.

My question has nothing to do with the algorithm.

I would like to keep original `HashMap` and assign it to the modified map at the end of the outer for-loop, but the original `HashMap` is modified even though I never modify the `originalMap` in the code.

I am not sure if I am doing wrong.

**Code**:

```
void find2(String string) {
    int n = string.length();
    int occurrence = n / 4;
    Map<Character, Integer> cache = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    char[] original = { 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T' };
    for (char c : original) {
        cache.put(c, 0);
    }
    char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
    char[] modifiableChars = string.toCharArray();

    HashMap<Character, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (int ii = 0; ii < string.length(); ii++) {
        char currentChar = chars[ii];
        if (!countMap.containsKey(currentChar)) {
            countMap.put(currentChar, 1);
        } else {
            Integer count = countMap.get(currentChar);
            count++;
            countMap.put(currentChar, count);
        }
    }
    HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    HashMap<Character, Integer> originalMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (int ii = 0; ii < string.length(); ii++) {
        char c = string.charAt(ii);
        if (!map.containsKey(c)) {
            map.put(c, 1);
        } else {
            Integer count = map.get(c);
            count++;
            map.put(c, count);
        }
        if (!originalMap.containsKey(c)) {
            originalMap.put(c, 1);
        } else {
            Integer count = originalMap.get(c);
            count++;
            originalMap.put(c, count);
        }
    }
    int min = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        int change = 0;

        int checkCount = countMap.get(chars[i]);
        if (checkCount <= occurrence) {
            continue;
        }



        boolean isValidated = false;
        int j = i;
        for (j = i; j < chars.length; j++) {
            char c = chars[j];
            int count = map.get(c);
            if (count > occurrence) {

            }
            char nextChar = getNextChar(map, cache, occurrence);
            if (nextChar == ' ') {
                continue;
            }
            Integer nextCharCount = map.get(nextChar);
            nextCharCount++;
            map.put(nextChar, nextCharCount);
            chars[j] = nextChar;

            if (c != nextChar) {
                Integer currentCount = map.get(c);
                currentCount--;
                map.put(c, currentCount);
            }

            change++;
            // validate the characters.
            if (isValid(chars, occurrence)) {
                isValidated = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isValidated) {
            if (min == 0) {
                min = change;
            } else {
                min = Math.min(min, change);
            }
        }
        chars = string.toCharArray();
        map = originalMap; // <--------
    }
    System.out.println(min);
}
```

Comment: `a = someMap` does not create a copy of `someMap` if that's the question. If you want a copy, use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap-java.util.Map-

Comment: a gist of what this piece of code is suppose to do? You mentioned you didn't modify `originalMap` but I'm seeing code like `originalMap.put(c, 1);`

Comment: the for-loop below the 'HashMap<Character, Integer> originalMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();' is initializing the originalMap to contain the original count of each letter, because 'map' is modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do

```
Map map = new HashMap(); // generic later
map.putAll(originalMap);
```

instead of

```
map = originalMap;
```

this only changes the reference to point to original hashmap. So in the second iteration original hashmap is modified. what you need is to create copy.

Comment: Ah.. I see why.. thanks.

Comment: please accept it as answer. If it solves the problem

Comment: What if `map` is ahead of  `originalMap` by some extra entries. Will `putAll` discard them at first? No, it won't. You may or may not have unintended entries after `putAll` operation. So, it's NOT a safe option.

Comment: @Saurav Sahu is right btw. putAll doesnt remove old entries. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new hashmap which is copy of original one, at the very beginning while entering inside the `for` loop:

```
Map<SomeType, OtherType> map1 = new HashMap<SomeType, OtherType>(original);
```

I would **not recommend using `putAll`** as it doesn't discard the already present entries in the target `hashmap`. [Demo](http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/qubsk6)

```
   HashMap newmap1 = new HashMap();
   HashMap newmap2 = new HashMap();

   // populate hash map
   newmap1.put(1, "tutorials");
   newmap1.put(2, "point");
   newmap1.put(3, "is best");
   newmap2.put(5, "Foo");

   System.out.println("Values in newmap1: "+ newmap1);
   System.out.println("Values in newmap2: "+ newmap2);   
   newmap2.putAll(newmap1);
   System.out.println("Values in newmap2: "+ newmap2);
```

Gives output as :

```
Values in newmap1: {1=tutorials, 2=point, 3=is best}
Values in newmap2: {5=Foo}
Values in newmap2: {1=tutorials, 2=point, 3=is best, 5=Foo}
```

As you can see the entry `{5, "Foo"}` **remained intact** after using `putAll`, which is not expected when you wish to regain the original `hashmap`.

**EDIT:**

As, it is [suggested to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757868/map-clear-vs-new-map-which-one-will-be-better) *new* map instance creation as much as possible, use `.clear() + .putAll()` operations at the end of `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers where `map` is created at the start of the loop with a copy of the original map is nicer, but following the existing logic:

```
    map = originalMap; // <--------
```

should become

```
    map.clear();
    map.putAll(originalMap);
```

And a couple of tips:

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
```

can become the more abstract `Map`, and the inferred types `<>`

```
Map<Character, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();
```

With java 8:

```
    if (!countMap.containsKey(currentChar)) {
        countMap.put(currentChar, 1);
    } else {
        Integer count = countMap.get(currentChar);
        count++;
        countMap.put(currentChar, count);
    }
```

can become a one-liner

```
    countMap.merge(currentChar, 1, Integer::add);
                   ===========  =  ============
                    |           |     |
                    |           |    function(old, 1) when old value exists
                    |           |    returns new value or null to delete
                    |           |
                    |          new value when no value (or null value)
                   key
```

Comment: This is where I find C++ little convenient, just do `++mymap[key]` and all is good. :)

Comment: @SauravSahu yes aliases, `int&`, can come in handy.