# Java HashMap: Reinitialize A New Map vs map.clear() vs Just Put right away when inserting maps with same keys to a list

Tags: java, performance, optimization, hashmap

I would like to get to know which method is actually better to use when I need to create array containing many maps with exact same keys in it. I just think about 3 methods here:

1. Reinitialize the `new HashMap()`.

   ```
   Map t = new HashMap();
   t.put(k, v);
   list.add(t);
   t = new HashMap();
   t.put(k, v);
   list.add(t);
   // ... and so on
   ```
2. Use `map.clear()`.

   ```
   Map t = new HashMap();
   t.put(k, v);
   list.add(t);
   t.clear();
   t.put(k, v);
   list.add(t);
   // ... and so on
   ```
3. Just `put()` right away.

   ```
   Map t = new HashMap();
   t.put(k, v);
   list.add(t);
   t.put(k, v);
   list.add(t);
   // ... and so on
   ```

I have read the articles about the use of `new HashMap()` vs `map.clear()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757868/map-clear-vs-new-map-which-one-will-be-better/6763242). However, for performance-wise, I still look for "more-optimized" one. Thus, I decided to take a look of `put` method of Java Map.

When I take a look at Java doc of Map, I saw that the `put()` function is actually check if key exists before place the value. What it actually does is like below:

```
final V putVal(int hash, K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent,
                   boolean evict) {
        Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> p; int n, i;
        if ((tab = table) == null || (n = tab.length) == 0)
            n = (tab = resize()).length;
        if ((p = tab[i = (n - 1) & hash]) == null)
            tab[i] = newNode(hash, key, value, null);
        else {
            Node<K,V> e; K k;
            if (p.hash == hash &&
                ((k = p.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                e = p;
            else if (p instanceof TreeNode)
                e = ((TreeNode<K,V>)p).putTreeVal(this, tab, hash, key, value);
            else {
                for (int binCount = 0; ; ++binCount) {
                    if ((e = p.next) == null) {
                        p.next = newNode(hash, key, value, null);
                        if (binCount >= TREEIFY_THRESHOLD - 1) // -1 for 1st
                            treeifyBin(tab, hash);
                        break;
                    }
                    if (e.hash == hash &&
                        ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                        break;
                    p = e;
                }
            }
            if (e != null) { // existing mapping for key
                V oldValue = e.value;
                if (!onlyIfAbsent || oldValue == null)
                    e.value = value;
                afterNodeAccess(e);
                return oldValue;
            }
        }
        ++modCount;
        if (++size > threshold)
            resize();
        afterNodeInsertion(evict);
        return null;
    }
```

Suppose that the data is so so many (just say 10000 maps to be inserted to the list and each map has 100 key-value pairs) What is actually the best practice for the performance:

1. Time-wise (Runtime)
2. Resource-wise (Memory)

among these three methods while considering the data integrity (expected result is no any mistake for each maps inside the list)?

Comment: Only your first option uses multiple maps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Map.clear() vs new Map : Which one will be better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757868/map-clear-vs-new-map-which-one-will-be-better)

Comment: @SaifAhmad That's the article I mentioned in my question :) . However it doesn't answer about the comparison of them vs using put right away

Answer (score 1):

Only your first version will work at all!! The two others ones will add always the ***same*** map to the list!!! So the questions regarding performance or resource utilisation are futile.

As all instance have the same contents, `equals()` on the list entries will always return `true`, but for your versions 2 and 3, also `==` on them would return `true`.

If this is intended, why populating a list with the map?

`List.add()` will *not* store a copy of the instance referenced by the argument (at least not in Java), it will just keep the reference.