# Emptying an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<OrderItem> orderItems = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();
```

It is filled with objects.
I want to press a button that would effectively delete all the objects in this list. How can I do this?

Comment: Learning to research the javadocs is a key skill.  You can't write Java well without it.

Comment: SO is not a substitute for the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).

Answer (score 4):

Use [clear() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

```
 orderItems.clear();
```

And

> The main thing to be concerned about is what other code might have a reference to the list.

Prefer to read @Skeets answer : [Better practice to re-instantiate a List or invoke clear()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823398/better-practice-to-re-instantiate-a-list-or-invoke-clear)

Answer (score 3):

Use [clear() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear%28%29) like this `orderItems.clear()`
It Removes all of the elements from this list. The list will be empty after this call returns.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ArrayList#clear()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear%28%29) .

> Removes all of the elements from this list. The list will be empty after this call returns.

With `clear()` , you don't need to create a new `ArrayList` object . It just empties the `ArrayList`.

```
orderItems.clear();
orderItems.trimToSize();
```

Answer (score 1):

Collection interface itself defines a `void clear();` method.

```
/**
 * Removes all of the elements from this collection (optional operation).
 * The collection will be empty after this method returns.
 *
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the <tt>clear</tt> operation
 *         is not supported by this collection
 */
```

In your buttons actionListner just use `orderItems.clear();`. This will remove all elements of that  Collection(ArrayList in your case).

```
    myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            orderItems.clear();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `ActionListener` to your button where you set

```
orderItems = new ArrayList();
```

That would delete every item in the list.

Comment: That's a new variable with the same name --> would not compile.

Comment: @jlordo it would definitely compile, but you'd shadow the orderItems field and not much would happen at all.

Comment: @kritzikratzi: that's correct.

Comment: @jlordo Edited. Don't know how that happened.

Comment: @AdrianJandl: revoked my downvote, even though it is still not precise. This won't delete any item out of a list, it creates a new list and assigns it to the variable. If the other list isn't referenced any more, it is eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: @jlordo You're right. Though it depends on what the OP means by "delete". It will provide him with an empty ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

There is one inbuilt method in ArrayList.So you can implement it on orderdItems like:

```
orderedItems.clear()
```

Also check this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

You can empty the ArrayList by calling the clear method

orderItems.clear();