# Replace one array list with other list

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

In my business logic, I want to replace one list completely with another list.

Is the below approach correct?

```
public class TestListReplacement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> values= new ArrayList<String>();
        values.add("a");
        values.add("b");
        values.add("c");
        values.add("d");
        values.add("e");
        values.add("f");

        List<String> valuesNew= new ArrayList<String>();
        valuesNew.add("g");
        valuesNew.add("h");
        valuesNew.add("i");
        valuesNew.add("j");
        valuesNew.add("k");

        values= valuesNew;
        for(String val:values){
            System.out.println(val);
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine, but I want to know if in some use cases, it might not work.

Comment: its correct and will work all the time

Comment: Your code isn't doing anything specific with the lists. It simply shows a variable's object reference being overwritten with a different object reference. If you're trying to update the values within the existing list, that's not what your code is doing. If you're expecting other places in your code that are referring to that list to see the new values, that won't happen. Based on your description above, and the isolated code sample, it's not clear what problem you're trying to address, and whether your solution works or not.

Comment: Actually, this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823398/better-practice-to-re-instantiate-a-list-or-invoke-clear (and a few others).

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, what about

```
values.clear(); // delete original contents in the list
values.addAll(valuesNew); // insert everything in the new list
```

To add some more context from answers from @nbrooks and others: 
Overwriting the reference isn't always an option and, frankly, the perceived inefficiency of iterating over the collection twice is almost always irrelevant in practice. If you need to retain the same list instance (because it's being referred to at other places in the code) overwriting the variable doesn't update those other places.

Comment: @Jonny Because if the list is a member of some other class, the latter has no effect? Different problems have different solutions, and this answer is the most straightforward to replace all the values in a given list with new values. Overwriting the variable does nothing to change other references to the initial, existing list.

Comment: @nbrooks isn't calling `clear()` wasting time? you would rather simply get rid of the reference and the GC would do the dirty work for you,

Comment: @Debosmit It depends on the OP's use-case, which they haven't provided. Overwriting the reference isn't always an option and, frankly, the perceived inefficiency of iterating over the collection twice is almost always irrelevant in practice. If you need to retain the same list instance (because it's being referred to at other places in the code) overwriting the variable doesn't update those other places.

Comment: @nbrooks I completely overlooked the fact that there could be other references in other locations that would cause exceptions. Thank you so much for the note. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: @Jonny I won't bother typing up an answer for this one, since the question's already been answered in a few places. There's a similar response [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3823430/803925).

Comment: Thanks @nbrooks, edited to add suggested explanation.

Comment: Also thanks @JonnyHenly.